# R, ggplot stacked bar-chart with position = "fill" and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm working with `ggplot2`, stacked barplot to 100% with relative values, using the `position = "fill"` option in `geom_bar()`.

Here my code:

```
test <- data.frame (x = c('a','a','a','b','b','b','b')
        ,k = c('k','j','j','j','j','k','k')
        ,y = c(1,3,4,2,5,9,7))

plot <- ggplot(test, aes(x =x, y = y, fill = k)) 
plot <- plot + geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") 
plot <- plot +  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#99ccff", "#ff6666"))
plot <- plot  + geom_hline(yintercept = 0.50)+ggtitle("test")
plot
```

Here the result:

[image]

However, I need to add the labels on the various bars, also on the "sub bars". To do this, I worked with the geom_text():

```
plot  + geom_text(aes(label=y, size=4))
```

But the result is not good. I tried without luck the `hjust` and `vjust` parameters, and also using something like:

```
plot  + geom_text(aes(label=y/sum(y), size=4))
```

But I did not reach the result needed (I'm not adding all the tests to not overload the question with useless images, if needed, please ask!). 
Any idea about to have some nice centered labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`label` specifies *what* to show, and `y` specifies `where` to show. Since you are using proportions for y-axis with `position = "fill"`, you need to calculate the label positions (`geom_text(aes(y = ...))`) in terms of proportions *for each* `x` using cumulative sums. Additionally, to display only the total proportion of a given color, you will need to extract the Nth row for each x, k combination. Here, I am building a separate `test_labels` dataset for use in `geom_text` to display the custom labels:

```
test <- data.frame (x = c('a','a','a','b','b','b','b'),
                    k = c('k','j','j','j','j','k','k'),
                    y = c(1,3,4,2,5,9,7))

test_labels = test %>%
  arrange(x, desc(k)) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(ylabel_pos = cumsum(y)/sum(y),
         ylabel = y/sum(y)) %>%
  group_by(k, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(ylabel = sum(ylabel)) %>%
  slice(n())

 ggplot(test, aes(x =x, y = y, fill = k)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#99ccff", "#ff6666")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.50) + 
  geom_text(data = test_labels, 
            aes(y = ylabel_pos, label=paste(round(ylabel*100,1),"%")), 
            vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5) +
  ggtitle("test")
```

**Result:**

```
> test_labels
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   x, k [4]
       x      k     y ylabel_pos    ylabel
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1      a      j     4  1.0000000 0.8750000
2      a      k     1  0.1250000 0.1250000
3      b      j     5  1.0000000 0.3043478
4      b      k     7  0.6956522 0.6956522
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your answer and explaination, very neat. So is it not possible to you to have only the values "of the colors",i.e. for the a column 12.5 for the pink and 87.5 for the light blue, and  for the  b column 69.6 for the pink and 30.4 for the light blue?

Comment: @nhl Yes, that is possible, but it will be a little more complicated. See my updated answer. I originally misunderstood your question.

Comment: Not a problem, maybe I've written it not perfectly clear. Awesome, thanks a lot! Could I ask you an opinion? Given your experience, is it absurd this "big" workaround to have the desired result discussed? `Ggplot2 `is awesome, but sometimes it seems not too much user friendly (like double scales, despite I've read why it should be not possible).

Comment: @nhl `ggplot()` is very customization, which is the main reason I think it has a somewhat steep learning curve. If you find `ggplot()` to be too complicated to do something that should be quite simple, you can often do it with simpler syntax using `qplot()`. I would recommend though, that you learn `ggplot` to begin with, since the skill builds up really quickly ones you get the hang of it and you can create awesome plots in no time. It's basically adding complexity with layers of plot elements. Plus, the documentation for `ggplot2` is very well-written.

Comment: @nhl By double scales, I assume you meant dual axis with different scales. Not allowing for this functionality is actually by design, and has nothing to do with `ggplot2`'s user-friendliness. Dual axis is actually possible with `sec_axis`, but the second axis has to be a one-to-one transformation of the first. Plots with dual axis with _different scales_ (not one-to-one transformation) are deemed misleading, since you are basically trying to compare two things that are unrelated.